# regex to find 5 digits that follow a ', XX

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

I am trying to find a way via python regex to capture a 5 digit zipcode; the problem is there is multiple 5 digits that are not zipcodes in my document(s).

The only way I have found to isolate them is if, via regex; I can use the below as a handle `', following a state abbreviation` so ' **5 digits following** `', XX` '.

*i.e.* `, VA 23220`

```
, VA 22801
```

Comment: use `re.findall(r', [A-Z]{2} (\d{5})\b', text)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use positive look-behind regex:

```regex
(?<=, [A-Z]{2} )\d{5}
```

will produce

```
22801
```

See it in action: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CecgGn/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is use a capture group in `search`

```
>>> text = 'some text, VA 20166 some other text 123'
>>> print re.search(r', [A-Z]{2} (\d{5})\b', text).group(1)
20166
```

Comment: I think `r',\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+(\d{5})\b'`, i.e. you need at least one space after the comma. Our addresses are `City, State Zip-Code`

Comment: If only one zip code is expected to be matched - `re.finall` is an overhead,  `re.search` would be an optimized approach

Comment: I think rather than using `\s` you should use a simple space character since with American addresses `City, State Zip-Code` such as `Springfield Gardens, NY 11413' `are always on the same line and the OP, I believe, is trying to give more context to 5-digit numbers by looking for actual addresses.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson: Thanks for your comments. I edited answer as per your good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

With regex lookbehind:

```
import re

s = 'some text , VA 22801 some other text 123'
m = re.search(r'(?<=,\s[A-Z]{2}\s)\d{5}\b', s)
zip_code = m.group() if m else m
print(zip_code)   # 22801
```

Comment: Your regex matches `12345` in `'TOM, PETE, AL\n12345,78901,12876'`where the white space is a newline. Is that really what you want? Generally the state and zip code are separated by just one or more spaces in the pattern `City, State Zip-Code`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson, you make wrong considerations when saying "Is that really what you want?". If a newline would be an issue I would wait a notation from the OP

Comment: When I say, "Is that really what you want", I admit that it is a rhetorical question. So this was my point, even if I may be second-guessing the OP: The OP is trying to pick out Zip-Codes, which are 5-digit numbers. To do so he is trying to provide context and that context is the fact that Zip-Codes are part of addresses which are *generally* in the format of `Name\nStreet Address\nCity, State Zip-Code`. Which is to say, that the City, State and Zip-Code are always on the same line. Thus, the Zip-Code is preceded by a `, XX ` where `XX` is a 2-letter state abbreviation.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @CaptainRon, looks like you tested a string that doesn't contain a zip code , see my update

Comment: Why do I need the .group() ?

Comment: @CaptainRon, because this is regex ... in Python, not just regex by itself

Comment: I've gotten my other zipcodes with this:                                 zip_code = re.search(r'(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{5}\-\d{4})(?:[^\d]|$)', clean_content)

Comment: @CaptainRon, why mentioning "other zipcodes" only this time? All the conditions and nuances should be specified in your question beforehand. Why do you think you've got 3 downvotes to your question?